# Where do transaction fees go in block #163368

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

The reward of the Coinbase TX  is only 50 BTC not including transaction fees. So who owned  these fees?

Comment: 163369 includes transactions fees, you are meaning 163368 or 163370?

Comment: sorry. my mistake. I mean 163368

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned [this Block](https://blockchain.info/block/0000000000000048567353a28610ba10375850ca291014e2fda18ef216dc2033) and also some other ones in the blockchain as well failed to claim the fees. Some miners missed all fees other only  a few, this can happen for a variety of reasons, almost all of them are bugs in the mining software.

> So who owned these fees?

These coins are lost, the miner failed to claim them and so they are gone.

Comment: Or rather, they were never created.

Comment: @Matthieu what do you mean with "never created"?